# For my Caesar Cipher code, its saying the index is out of range when it is not?

Tags: python

This is my code for a Caesar Cipher encrypter. When I test it with the letter "d", Python says the index is out of range, but I made sure that it was in range by modding the index.

```py
shift = 23
lower_alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
list_lower_alph = list(lower_alph)
upper_alph = lower_alph.upper()
shifted_lower = lower_alph[23:] + lower_alph[:23]
shifted_upper = upper_alph[23:] + upper_alph[:23]


def encrypt(w):
    word = []
    for i in w:
        if i in list_lower_alph:
            lowerindex = lower_alph.index(i)
            lowerindex = lowerindex + shift
            if lowerindex > 26:
                lowerindex = lowerindex % 26
            word.append(lower_alph[lowerindex])
        elif i in list_upper_alph:
            upperindex = upper_alph.index(i)
            upperindex = upperindex + shift
            if upperindex > 26:
                upperindex = upperindex % 26
            word.append(upper_alph[upperindex])
            print(upperindex)
        elif i not in list_lower_alph and list_upper_alph:
            word.append(i)
    print(''.join(word))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    encrypt("d")
```

This is the error I got

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jaewon/Downloads/assign3-transform-f20/assign3-transform f20/CaesarCipher.py", line 34, in <module>
        encrypt("d")
  File "C:/Users/Jaewon/Downloads/assign3-transform-f20/assign3-transform-f20/CaesarCipher.py", line 22, in encrypt word.append(lower_alph[lowerindex])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Strings are zero-indexed, so the valid indexes for `lowerindex` are 0 through 25.  `lowerindex[26]` is out of range, just as the error says.

Comment: I expect you want `if lowerindex > 25:` rather than `if lowerindex > 26:` in both places it occurs. ( or `if lowerindex >= 26:`)

Comment: I think you're also missing this line, or something like it, at the top of your code: `list_upper_alph = list(lower_alph.upper())`

Comment: ...and this line probably isn't doing what you think it is `elif i not in list_lower_alph and list_upper_alph:` ... should be `elif i not in list_lower_alph and i not in list_upper_alph:`, and if that's true, you really just need `else:` there, as that condition will, always be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is little untidy, but I think the following code is suitable for your purpose.

```
def encrypt(word, shift):
    alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    ALPH = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    encrypt_word = ""
    for ch in word:
        if ch in alph:
            encrypt_word += alph[(alph.find(ch)+shift) % 26]
        elif ch in ALPH:
            encrypt_word += ALPH[(ALPH.find(ch)+shift) % 26]
        else:
            encrypt_word += ch
    return encrypt_word

if __name__ == "__main__":
    word = "aB#c*U"
    ew = encrypt(word, 23)
    print(ew)
```